# Accessing variables in Django forms

Tags: django, django-forms, django-formwizard

The problem I've run into here is how to display some additional text in a form, 
specifically the values of the previous step. The point is to show the user a message such as "you have chosen {{ value_from_step_0 }} as your starter, now choose a main course."

I can get that value from step 0 as follows:

```
class MenuWizard(SessionWizardView):
    def get_form_kwargs(self, step=None):
        kwargs = {}
        if step == '1':
            starter = self.get_cleaned_data_for_step('0')['starter']
            kwargs.update({'starter': starter})

class MainCourseForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        starter = kwargs.pop('starter')
        print "{0} chosen".format(starter) # This works
        super(DomainForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # What next?
```

If I don't pop the 'starter' value then the super call fails. But, how may I get that value into the relevant template? Presumably I need to do something further within **init** or override something else, but what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that 1.7 is unsupported, and the form wizards were removed from Django in 1.8 and are now in the third-party formtools library.

This isn't really a job for the form, but the view. SessionWizardView is a standard class-based view, and like most class-based views it allows you to override `get_context_data` to add elements to the template contents. See [the documentation](http://django-formtools.readthedocs.org/en/latest/wizard.html#formtools.wizard.views.WizardView.get_context_data), which has an example of using `self.steps.current` to check the current step name.

Comment: Thanks, that's solved the template issue. I am in fact using 1.8 with formtools but had trouble following that documentation.